# I am facing this kind of error when I am going to create flutter app in vs code, How I fix this error?

Tags: flutter, vscode-extensions

when I have gone to create a new flutter project, below error is raised. How should I solve it?

The following error occurred.

```
[my_test_app] flutter create --template app --overwrite .
Waiting for another flutter command to release the startup lock...
Creating project ....
Running "flutter pub get" in my_test_app...
Resolving dependencies...
Connection closed before full header was received
pub get failed
command: "C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart 
__deprecated_pub --directory . get --example"
pub env: {
     "FLUTTER_ROOT": "C:\src\flutter",
     "PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "vscode.dart-code:flutter_cli:create",
     "PUB_CACHE": "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache",}exit code: 69
```

Comment: Please consider taking the time to read [ask] and, in particular how to give your question a meaningful title and how to provide a [mre].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please maintain a good network connection in your initial app,it will download all the necessary plugins and gradle so the network is must